# XAML file conflict in C# cmake build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, cmake

I have a C# CMake project here, https://github.com/jarl-haggerty/cmake-test.  It consists of two libraries which contain a UserControl1.xaml but with different namespaces.  If I generate a Visual Studio 2019 solution and alternate between building the two libraries I get the following error when I build library One:

```
1>C:\Users\jarl\source\repos\test\One\UserControl1.xaml.cs(9,13,9,32): error CS0103: The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context
1>C:\Users\jarl\source\repos\test\build\obj\x64\Debug\UserControl1.xaml(9,95,9,117): error CS1061: 'UserControl1' does not contain a definition for 'innerRect_MouseDownTwo' and no accessible extension method 'innerRect_MouseDownTwo' accepting a first argument of type 'UserControl1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

If I delete all the files in obj/x64/Debug then the build starts working again.  This folder appears to be the destination of build files in both libraries and from the error it sounds like the two versions of UserControl.xaml are getting mixed up.  A C++ project would separate the builds in One.dir and Two.dir folders.  Is this to be expected?  Is there a workaround?  I'm trying to port a Visual Studio project with a couple cases like this to cmake.

Comment: What is your project type, UWP, WPF or others?

Comment: I think it's WPF.  The repo I linked to reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I put the add_library calls in separate CMakeLists.txt files (One/CMakeLists.txt and Two/CMakeLists.txt) then the builds run in different folders which resolves my problem.